# Implement checkbox in navigation drawer items

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Is there a way to implement the checkbox selection in Navigation drawer

Comment: post navigation drower menu code here to better help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom View in your Navigation menu item using `app:actionLayout="@layout/[Your layour]"`

Example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <!--Other menu here-->

    <item xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:id="@+id/sample_key"
          android:title="Custom item"
          app:actionLayout="@layout/sample_layout"
          app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```